# Exclude returned data when specific words or phrases exist

Tags: sql, where-clause

An example follows of data that is being returned.

| ID | CensoredWord | DescriptionSnippet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | anus | anus |
| 2 | anus | manuscript submitted |
| 3 | anus | tetanus vaccination |
| 4 | anus | oceanus proposal |
| 5 | rere | prerequisite includes |

The Description Snippet contains the censored word within another word or within a phrase and could be multiple sentences long.

I'd like to exclude data from being returned when the word is anus and the snippet contains the word tetanus or manuscript or oceanus and likewise with the word rere and the snippet contains prerequisite.

I've attempted various methods around WHERE

CensoredWord = 'anus' and DescriptionSnippit NOT LIKE '%tetanus%'

OR CensoredWord = 'anus' and DescriptionSnippit NOT LIKE '%manuscript%'

OR CensoredWord = 'anus' and DescriptionSnippit NOT LIKE '%oceanus%'

OR CensoredWord = 'rere' and DescriptionSnippit NOT LIKE '%prerequisite%'

But I am coming up short. What should this look like?

Comment: I chuckled a little.

Comment: It seems like you want something more like this.  `WHERE NOT (word = 'anus' AND descr LIKE '%xxx%' OR word = 'rera' AND descr LIKE '%yyy%' OR ...)` ... I'll add this as an answer if the guess is correct.  It seems like you may have asked the wrong question.  I'm just not sure.

Comment: Should `DescriptionSnippet` on line with ID=1 not be `tetanus` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp that searched for description_snippets that have at least one letter before or after the censored_word.

```
select * from test where lower(description_snippet) regexp lower(concat("[[:alpha:]]",censored_word,"|",censored_word,"[[:alpha:]]"));
```

Or use like

```
select * from test where lower(description_snippet) like (concat('%',lower(censored_word))) or lower(description_snippet) like(concat(lower(censored_word),"%"));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a471f3/7

Comment: We don't know the OP's specific RDBMS, not all support the use of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just don't want the sentence to contain the censored word, but ignore words that contain it.

Then this will work for most SQL dialects.
But it's not perfect.
F.e. it won't find `anus!`

```
select *
from test
where concat(' ',description_snippet,' ') not like 
concat('% ',censored_word,' %')
```

Some RDBMS's have functions that accept regular expressions.   Which gives more flexibility.
F.e. the use of word-boundaries.

Here's an example that works in Postgresql

**Test**

> ```
> create table test (
>  ID serial primary key, 
>  censored_word varchar(30),
>  description_snippet varchar(30)
> );
>
> insert into test (id, censored_word, description_snippet) values
>   (1, 'anus', 'anus')
> , (2, 'anus', 'manuscript submitted')
> , (3, 'anus', 'tetanus vaccination') 
> , (4, 'anus', 'oceanus proposal')
> , (5, 'rere', 'prerequisite includes')
> , (6, 'rere', 'no rere without anus')
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from test
> where description_snippet !~ concat('\m(', censored_word, ')\M')
> ```

| id | censored_word | description_snippet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | anus | manuscript submitted |
| 3 | anus | tetanus vaccination |
| 4 | anus | oceanus proposal |
| 5 | rere | prerequisite includes |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bf33262c8fbe902251a59869f8c85136)*